# Losing leading 0 from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get correct zip code from city and state values. But I am losing leading 0s from zip code.

Example

```
create procedure sp_getCorrectvalue
as
Begin
     declare @value as nvarchar(5)
     set @value = '00254'
     return @value
End

declare @getValue as nvarchar(5)
Exec @getValue = sp_getCorrectvalue
select @getValue as zipCode
```

it should return `00254`, but it returns `254` which is not correct

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged for Oracle and MySQL?  It appears to be a SQL Server specific question unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: i apologize John, but the purpose for adding those tags is those folks  also can answer this question if they know. for this you dont need to - vote it. If you know the answer you can answer it rather than looking into tags of questions. Those tags are related to this question. This is common database question.

Comment: Abhi, Regardless of why you did it, it is not the correct way to get help on this site.

Comment: This is common database question. I am new to database and coding just need help

Comment: Welcome and we are happy to help!  If you are serious about getting help, please follow the rules :)

Comment: I will and i apologize, thanks for help

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getCorrectvalue()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN
     declare @value as nvarchar(5)
     set @value = '00254'
     return @value
END
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29fa9/1/0

---

Stored procedures return an integer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

> Stored procedures can return an integer value to a calling procedure or an application

Answer (score 7):

The return value from a procedure can only be an `int`, so it gets converted when you return it. To return a string you need to return it in the result or in an output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm getting a similar issue in Mysql
I have a Stored Procedure that takes a Student ID IN Char(8).  If the ID is '00002563' and has as Out that is VarChar.

If I pass in '00002563' and pass it to the put parameter... All if get is '2563' in the varchar.

The original intent of the procedure is for the student to enter their ID and for the procedure to process it and determine their assigned dorm and room number if found.

THey are all NOT Found..and I suspect the reason is that the varchar is being converted to an INT.

Comment: If you have a question that is not answered here, please post a new question. You can link to this question in your new question if you need to reference it.